# jquery plugging $(this) into a separate function

Tags: jquery, each

hey I have a function set up like so:

```
var smallerHeight_css = function() {
    var sizeVariable = ".06";
    var smallerHeight_height = DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupHEIGHT * sizeVariable;

    $(this).find(".groundup-hotspotCircle").css({
        height:smallerHeight_height,
        width:"auto"
    });     
    $(this).find(".groundup-hotspotPadding, .groundup-hotspotContent-container").css({
        height:smallerHeight_height 
    });
    $(this).find(".groundup-hotspotTitle").css({
        height:smallerHeight_height -5,
        width:smallerHeight_height - 5,
        borderRadius:smallerHeight_height,
        top:"50%",
        left:"50%",
        marginLeft:((smallerHeight_height -5) * ".5") * -1,
        marginTop:((smallerHeight_height -5) * ".5") * -1
    });
    $(this).find(".groundup-hotspotPadding").css({
        width:0
    });
    $(this).find(".groundup-hotspotContent-container").css({
        width:0
    });
};
```

I'd like to be able to call it in a .each function, but I'm not sure how to reference the $(this).  Right now I have it set up like so and it doesn't work.  Any help would be great!

```
if (DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupHEIGHT < DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupWIDTH) {
    $(".groundup-hotspot-container").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
            smallerHeight_css(); 
        } else if ( $(this).hasClass("expanded") ) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe pass in *$(this)* as a parameter:

```
if (DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupHEIGHT < DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupWIDTH) {
    $(".groundup-hotspot-container").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
            smallerHeight_css($(this)); 
        } else if ( $(this).hasClass("expanded") ) {
           //do something
        }
    });

}

                       //see the parameter, el?
var smallerHeight_css = function(el) {
    var sizeVariable = ".06";
    var smallerHeight_height = DISCOVERY_GROUNDUP.groundupHEIGHT * sizeVariable;

    el.find(".groundup-hotspotCircle").css({
        height:smallerHeight_height,
        width:"auto"
    });     
    el.find(".groundup-hotspotPadding, .groundup-hotspotContent-container").css({
        height:smallerHeight_height 
    });

    //.....etc....
```

Answer (score 1):

On the context you're setting it, `this` on the  `smallerHeight_css` function is probably the global object.

If you want to bind to each current element, you can try binding the element directly to the function, like so:

```
$(".groundup-hotspot-container").each(function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass("collapsed") ) {
        (smallerHeight_css.bind(this))(); 
    } else if ( $(this).hasClass("expanded") ) {

    }
});
```

Using `bind` turns `this` in `smallerHeight_css` into the current element on the .each loop.

That works for the example you set up, though it'd be preferable to pass the element to the function.

Comment: I like this answer. Sets the context of $(this) in the smallerHeight_css() function to the 'this' in the .each method